# React JS material-ui itemlist dialog is not closing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, dialog, material-ui

I am making todolist with material ui and react.
I have a problem.
I tried to make click event that opens a dialog with detail informations when listitem is clicked. 
However when i try to close the dialog, the dialog doesn't close.
Here is the code i wrote for the test.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemAvatar from '@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar';
import ListItemSecondaryAction from '@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowDown';
import ConfirmationNumberIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ConfirmationNumber';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import { QuestItem } from '../common/interfaces';

interface IProps {
  quest: QuestItem | null
}


export default function QuestEntry({ quest } : IProps) {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(quest?.checked);
  const [questopen, setQuestOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
  };
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setQuestOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    console.log("click");
    setQuestOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <ListItem button onClick={handleClickOpen}>
      <ListItemAvatar>
        <Avatar>
          <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
        </Avatar>
      </ListItemAvatar>
      <ListItemText
        primary={quest?.title}
      />
      <ListItemSecondaryAction>
        <Checkbox
          edge="end"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        {checked && (
        <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
          <ConfirmationNumberIcon />
        </IconButton>
        )}
        {!checked && (
        <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
          <DeleteIcon />
        </IconButton>
        )}
      </ListItemSecondaryAction>
      <Dialog open={questopen} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Quest Info</DialogTitle>
        {/* <DialogContent>
        </DialogContent> */}
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Close
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

I think there is connection between mouse focus on dialog. But I can't find any solution from googling please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handleClickOpen is triggered whenever your click on any item on the page dialog box.

You have added `onClick={handleClickOpen}` to `ListItem` instead of `Avatar`.

Just change that it will work as expected

```
<ListItem button> //from here
  <ListItemAvatar> 
    <Avatar onClick={handleClickOpen}> // to here
      <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
    </Avatar>
  </ListItemAvatar>
  <ListItemText primary={"hello"} />
 ......rest of the code
```

Comment: ListItemAvatar doesn't have onClick function :( is there any other way to make click event for the items?

Comment: Just add and run it will work,
you can also add to Avatar or KeyboardArrowDownIcon any of them will work. 
But onClick should be added to parent so  ListItemAvatar is the best bet let me know.

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work. It keep says ListItemAvatar doesn't have onClick function.

Comment: That's absurd did you try on Avatar because it's working for me.
Here is the working example of your code https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-https-mg6fx?file=/src/Question.js

Comment: Oh I was keep trying on ListItemAvatar. Sorry for not looking closely.